# images of graphs getting distorted and blurred when merged into final PNG file using matplotlib

Tags: python, image, matplotlib, debugging, png

I want to display some plot graphs , a single graph when converted to png doesnt cause any problem but when i have to display multiple plot graphs with the table in png format the graph gets blurred.

I am using matplotlib.pyplot to read graph images and add it to the final png file where all graphs can be displayed but images are getting blurred in final png file which i donot want.

This is the final code that merges all png files from there plot_file representing the path of the stored graph images into one png.

```
tables = [tabulate(df, headers='keys', tablefmt='fancy_grid') for df in all_dataframes]

# Create a plot to display the tables
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(16, 6))

# Turn off axis
ax.axis('off')

# Define the positions and heights for each table in the plot
table_spacing = 2
table_positions = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
table_heights = [0.15] * len(all_dataframes)

# Add spacing between tables
table_positions = [pos - i * table_spacing for i, pos in enumerate(table_positions)]

# Display each table in the plot
for i, (table, pos, height, plot_file) in enumerate(zip(tables, table_positions, table_heights, all_plot_files)):
    ax.text(0, pos, table, va='top', fontfamily='monospace', fontsize=10)

    label = all_labels[i]  # Assuming each DataFrame has a name attribute
    ax.text(0, pos + height, f"{label}", va='top', fontfamily='monospace', fontsize=24, color='red')

    img = plt.imread(plot_file)
    axins = ax.inset_axes([0.6, pos, 0.4, height])
    axins.imshow(img)
    axins.axis('off')

# Save the tables as a single PNG file
output_png_path = 'Regional_Table.svg'
plt.savefig(output_png_path, bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches=0.2, format='svg')

# Show the saved PNG file path
print(f'Tables saved as: {output_png_path}')
```

Here is how i am generating a graph into an image and having its path

```
 plt.figure(figsize=(15, 7))
    # Exclude the last 5 columns (non-year columns)
    plt.plot(pivot_data.index, pivot_data[current_year - 4], label=str(current_year - 4))
    plt.plot(pivot_data.index, pivot_data[current_year - 1], label=str(current_year - 1))
    plt.plot(pivot_data.index, pivot_data[current_year], label=str(current_year))
    plt.plot(pivot_data.index, pivot_data['5yr range'], label='5yr range')
    plt.plot(pivot_data.index, pivot_data['5yr Avg'], label='5yr Avg', linestyle='dotted')
    plt.title(f'{label} - Pivot Data')
    plt.xlabel('')
    plt.ylabel('')
    plt.legend()

    # Save the plot as a PNG file
    plot_file_path = f'{label}_plot.png'
    plt.savefig(plot_file_path, bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches=0.2)
    plt.close()

    all_plot_files.append(plot_file_path)
```

[image: here the blurred image is appearing]

Comment: Why not plot the graphs directly in your inset axes with `axins.plot`, etc., rather than saving and reloading individual pngs?